# how can hide and show li tag in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angularjs 1.4.8. I'm trying to hide & show operation in `<li>`.

My code is given below:

```
<ul class="bk_crs_rslt">
  <li ng-repeat="c in courses"> 
    <h4>
      <a href="#" ng-click="show = !show"> {{c.CourseName }}
        <img src="image/bk_ad_btn.jpg" />
      </a>
    </h4>
    <p><span style="color:#337ab7;">{{c.CollegeName}}</span><br>{{c.CountryName}}</p>
    <p ng-show="show">
       <b>Tution Fee</b>     :  {{c.Fee}}<br>
       <b>Level</b>          :  {{c.LevelName}}<br>
       <b>Detail </b>        :  {{c.Detail}} <br>
       <b>Duration </b>      :   {{c.Duration}}<br>
       <b>Subject </b>       :  {{c.Subjec}}t<br>
       <b>IELTS Score </b>   :  {{c.Score}}<br />
     </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can hide & show in `<li>` tag? 
plunker given here
https://plnkr.co/edit/lsIypaBviXNvEi7Pwok4?p=info

its working in plunker but not working my solution?

Comment: Can you add a plunker and possibly put in your controller code as well?

Comment: hi  Srijith ,plunker is given here  https://plnkr.co/edit/lsIypaBviXNvEi7Pwok4?p=info

Comment: its workin in plunker but not working my solution?

Comment: If its working fine in the plunkr then it should work for ur solution as well...is it throwing any error

Comment: no error  Pankaj Kumar

Comment: its working thank you

Comment: its working now. but link caption either 'More information' or 'hide Information' how can it possible? now it show bot caption .i wish only one caption at a time. please helpme?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use show as property

Like this

```
<ul class="bk_crs_rslt">
  <li ng-repeat="c in courses" >
    <h4><a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show"> {{c.CourseName }}<img src="image/bk_ad_btn.jpg" /></a> </h4>
    <p ng-show="c.show"><span style="color:#337ab7;">{{c.CollegeName}}</span>
      <br>{{c.CountryName}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you Anik Islam Abhi. bt its not perform hide & show . it only hide the detail..i want to togling